# Google App Engine Eclipse plugin without using GWT

Tags: google-app-engine, gwt, gae-eclipse-plugin

I want to host a Java/AngularJS app on Google App Engine, and leverage the Eclipse plugin.  I figure the most straightforward way to do this is:

1. From within Eclipse, start a new Google Web Project.
2. Go to project properties and uncheck GWT and DataNucleus.
3. Delete the generated java classes and GWT related stuff so you have an appengine.web.xml, web.xml, WEB-INF/lib, log4j properties, and a few other files left.
4. Put index.html under the war folder, sister to favicon.ico.
5. Change web.xml **welcome file** to index.html
6. Deploy and test that index.html is visible.

Deployment via Eclipse works fine, but myapp.appspot.com/ and myapp.appspot.com/index.html both return 404.

*Simply put my use case is "how do I deploy an index.html to GAE (using Eclipse plugin) without the 800 pound guerilla that is GWT?"*

I was unable to find good documentation on this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unchecking **'Use Google Web Toolkit'** should be all you need to do to create a basic App Engine application without GWT, however, it will not create a sample `index.html` file. For that, you need to keep **'Generate project sample code'** checked. This *will* create some extra Java files for you that you'll need to delete, but it's the closest you can get to what you described in your question.